# How to handle SSL Certificate in IE using selenium with python?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, internet-explorer, ssl-certificate

I'm getting the error as per the image.
[Error_img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K0kYa.png)

I tried the following code to solve it.

**Method 1 :**

```
from selenium import webdriver

from selenium.webdriver.ie.options import Options

options = Options()

options.set_capability={"acceptInsecureCerts", True}

options.set_capability={"ignoreProtectedModeSettings":True, "ignoreZoomSetting":True}

driver = webdriver.Ie(options=options,executable_path='D:/
Project/Testing/IEDriverServer_Win32_3.150.1/IEDriverServer.exe')

driver.get(url)

options.set_capability={"ie.ensureCleanSession",True}

driver.close()
```

**Method 2:**

```
from selenium import webdriver

from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities

desired_capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.INTERNETEXPLORER.copy()

desired_capabilities['acceptInsecureCerts'] = True

driver = webdriver.Ie(capabilities=desired_capabilities,executable_path='E:/DriverServer_Win32_3.150.1/IEDriverServer.exe')

driver.get(url)

print(driver.title)

driver.close()
```

**Can't share the URL therefore I have just written URL word

I tried both code but it's not working

Is there any another solution ?**

Comment: Why the code is not working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `acceptInsecureCerts` capability doesn't work because IE doesn't allow to accept it. You can refer to [this link](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/4704#issuecomment-329539218) for more detailed information.

In IE 11, you can click the link **Go on to the webpage (not recommended)** as a workaround to bypass the SSL certificate error. This link has an id "overridelink". You can find the id using F12 dev tools.

I use this site: https://expired.badssl.com/  as an example, the sample code is like below:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities
import time

url = "https://expired.badssl.com/"

ieoptions = webdriver.IeOptions()
ieoptions.ignore_protected_mode_settings = True    

driver = webdriver.Ie(executable_path='IEDriverServer.exe', options=ieoptions)
driver.get(url)
time.sleep(3)
driver.find_element_by_id('moreInfoContainer').click()
time.sleep(3)
driver.find_element_by_id('overridelink').click()
```

It works well in IE 11, you can also try the same method.